# Different AMI based on AWS Region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any reasons that AWS AMI are different based on the region?
For example, if I try to launch an EC2 instance in Frankfurt I Got this AMI:

```
Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - *ami-a8221fb5*
```

While in Oregon:

```
Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - *ami-e7527ed7*
```

Note the different ami-version: **`ami-a8221fb5`** and **`ami-e7527ed7`**.
Is there any reasons?

And how can I build a cloudformation template that I can launch on both Frankfurt or Oregon without having to change the ami ?

Comment: For AWS provided images, I see no reason why they should have different AMI IDs. It makes deploying AMI-dependent instances across regions more cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use parameterized values, such as in this pretty good example:

> You can use an input parameter to refer to a specific value in a map
>   by using the Fn::FindInMap function. For example, suppose you have a
>   list of regions that map to a specific AMI. You can select the AMI
>   that your stack uses by specifying a region parameter when you create
>   the stack.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-input-conditional-parameters.html

Answer (score 4):

The reason for different AMIs in different region is related to the fact that you have to have thet actual image available in the region to be able to launch instances. (if you didn't you would basically have to transfer it from where it would be mastered - a transfer between distant regions would take a long time - so it would take a long time to launch new ec2 instances).

in theory, I guess you could have the same image id across multiple regions but that would just make it confusing in case the image bound to the id is not the same. not to mention that you probably don't want to push it to all regions (inter-region traffic is not free).

the choice that ec2 made here to have different ids per region gives you the maximum amount of control and flexibility without a high price.

for launching machines via cloudformation, you can definitely parametrize it the way E.J. Brennan describes it.

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed a tool to help create mappings for multiple regions (by looking up the corresponding AMI image ID for an image given a source AMI image ID and region).  It's written in boto3.  You may find it useful.  https://github.com/codesolid/ami-lookup.